# How to change (unknown) numbers of a file using bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting

I have an html file and I should change (with Bash) the numbers inside.
This is an example:

```
<TR><TD ALIGN=center><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>28</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>58</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>44</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>1220</B></FONT></TD>
<TR><TD ALIGN=center><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>29</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>57</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>43</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>730</B></FONT></TD>
<TR><TD ALIGN=center><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>30</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>56</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>41</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>736</B></FONT></TD>
```

I know that the numbers are all enclosed in the tag "`<B>`" and "`</B>`".

These numbers must all be multiplied by 3.

How can I do?

I'm trying to make a script without success.

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? What was your best attempt?

Comment: This could be done in single `awk` script, but I am bad at `awk`, so I would do it like this: 1. With `sed` Extract the number between `<B>[0-9]*</B>` and put it in front of the line. 2. With `awk` multiply it by 3. Would be just `awk '{ $1*=3 }1`. 3. Put the number back in the line with proper `sed`. [Here is a sed introduction](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) and the simplest way to learn regexes is [to play games like crosswords with it](https://regexcrossword.com/).

Comment: I'm trying with `sed` and `awk` but I can't figure out how to do it. The data I need to modify is in the midst of thousands of html lines (which I filter with a grep keeping only those that have the `<B>` tag) but then I can't do the replacement

Comment: `the midst of thousands of html lines` - then I advise [not to parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use a dedicated tool for html, `xmllint`, `xmlstarlet` etc.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` or `sed` may not be the best tool, but this could work:

```
awk -F'<B>|</B>' -v OFS= '{$2="<B>"$2*3"</B>"}1' file
<TR><TD ALIGN=center><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>84</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>174</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>132</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>3660</B></FONT></TD>
<TR><TD ALIGN=center><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>87</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>171</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>129</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>2190</B></FONT></TD>
<TR><TD ALIGN=center><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>90</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>168</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>123</B></FONT></TD>
<TD ALIGN=right><FONT SIZE="-1"><B>2208</B></FONT></TD>
```

Comment: Thanks, in your opinion what could be the best tool?
How can I rewrite the file with the updated data? If I write it again using `"> filename"` gives me a completely staggered file.
Is there a possibility to rewrite only the numerical data in the old file?
Is it also possible to round off the result?

Comment: @Ignazio to rewite data using  `awk`  then do: `awk 'my commands' file > tmp && mv tmp file`  Everything are possible, it just takes som more time,

Answer (score 1):

Use an HTML-aware tool to modify HTML. For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), you can write

```
open :F html file.html ;
for //b
    set . (3 * .) ;
save :F html :b ;
```